# Diagonal Difference in c

Tags: c

Consider the following code. I have to find the difference of both diagonals in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

    int n,a[100][100],sum1=0,sum2=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
        {
        for(int j=0;j<n;++j){

            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
             if(i==j) sum1+=a[i][j];
             else if((i+j)==(n-1)) sum2+=a[i][j];

        }
    }
     if(sum1>sum2) printf("%d",(sum1-sum2));
     else printf("%d",(sum2-sum1));


    return 0;
}
```

When I change `else if` to `if`, then the code works fine. Why?

Comment: What's the question? Why you get the wrong result? Consider the case of a 5x5 matrix for ex - The middle cell should contribute to both diagonal sums and if you use `else if`, it will only contribute to the first.

Comment: please edit this to ask a specific question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I get what you want to know:

```
if(i==j) sum1+=a[i][j];
if((i+j)==(n-1)) sum2+=a[i][j];
```

means that both cases could be valid, because you test them both.

On the other hand if you write

```
if(i==j) sum1+=a[i][j];
else if((i+j)==(n-1)) sum2+=a[i][j];
```

you are assuming only one of these conditions can run or none, but never both. So if the first term `(i==j)` is `true` the second one won't be tested anymore. But you need to test both for what you want to calculate. In fact `else if` always belongs to `if`, so at most only one condition can be met, while in the other version you just have two separate independent `ifs`.